# configure PyCharm for Odoo development in Windows Model not found

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo-11

> I wanna run Odoo on the ¨Pycharm with Python 3.6 as interp and i keep getting this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP4LJ.png)

> For The Debug Parameters

[Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuVIw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve that you need to:

1- Configure environment variables

After installing Odoo you need to go to Control Panel->System and Security-> System-> Advanced system settings->Environment Variables and search for Path on the System variables, inside the Path you need to add 2 new entries, one of them pointing to the python folder of your installed Odoo directory and the other one pointing to the Scripts folder inside the previous one.

2- Configure Pycharm interpreter

Go to File->Settings->Project Interpreter, and add a new Python Interpreter. You need to check on the Existing environment and search for the python.exe inside the Odoo installed directory, in my case es located in D:\Odoo 11.0\python\python.exe

3- Almost ready, configure Logs

In order to see the Logs of what your are doing you need to acces Odoo's log file into Pycharm. Click on Run->Edit Configurations->Logs tab and add a new log file, in my case my log file is located in D:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo.log, once you add your file and put the name you want press OK and check the options that start with Show console when...

In cases like yourself that Odoo is installed on the default directory on C: you need to open PyCharm as administrator

Ready to enjoy coding on Odoo with Pycharm

I hope this help you